# Images are opened differently when changing the Title

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm have a list of image paths I'm opening and showing using this:

```
    for path in image_paths:
        print 'Path for the this image is: "{}"'.format(path)
        img = cv2.imread(path)
        cv2.imshow("",img)
        cv2.waitKey(250)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And it opens each image for 250 ms in the center-ish of the screen and moves to next image, as expected. When I change the 1st parameter of `cv2.imshow("",img)` into `cv2.imshow("image {}".format(path[-7:-4]),img)` which shuold show the title *"image 001", "image XYZ"* and so on, the images are opened differntly:

The 1st is opened in the center-ish screen, and the second is opened a bit to the right and to the bottom, and so on, until it reaches some kind of limit and jumps to the upper left corner of some invisible frame. Why is this happening?

Comment: OpenCV uses the title to distinguish between multiple windows. In the first case, you're reusing the same window (since the title stays same). In the second case, the title changes, so a new window is created for each image.

Comment: Oh, is there an option to fix the location even if I use different titles?

Comment: I'd give [`cv::MoveWindow`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow) a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv2.imshow()` displays an image in a window but the first argument (*window title*) is used to create different windows.

When multiple calls to `cv2.imshow()` use the same *window title*, as in:

```
cv2.imshow("",img)
```

OpenCV creates a single window (with an empty name) that is reused every time a new image has to be displayed.

On the other hand, calling `cv2.imshow("image {}".format(path[-7:-4]), img)` in a loop will generate different *window titles* for every iteration of the loop, which in turn creates a new window on every call. So what you are seeing is the expected behaviour!

If you want several windows to appear at the same place of the screen, simply call `cv2.moveWindow()` after `cv.imshow()` with the appropriate screen coordinates:

```
window_title = "image {}".format(path[-7:-4])
cv2.imshow(window_title, img)
cv2.moveWindow(window_title, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 8):

`cv2.imshow()` displays the image in the window with the identifier passed as first argument. If no such window does exist, it is create and its title is set to the identifier.

Note that the window identifier and the window title are generally different things! If you want to show multiple images in the same window, but with different titles, you can use some fixed string in `imshow`. Then you call `cv2.setWindowTitle` to update the title to whatever you want.

```py
window_title = "image {}".format(path[-7:-4])
cv2.imshow("unique_window_identifier", img)
cv2.setWindowTitle("unique_window_identifier", window_title)
```

With another `imshow` call you can update the image and with another `setWindowTitle` you can update the title:

```py
cv2.imshow("unique_window_identifier", img2)
cv2.setWindowTitle("unique_window_identifier", window_title2)
```

Note that the `"unique_window_identifier"` string is never shown to the user, so you can use any unqiue string you want here.